# HVAC Furnace - Adding C Wire to Older Wiring Style

Tags: hvac, heat-pump

[image: Wiring]
[image: Thermostat]
[image: Schematic]Hello! Trying to add a smart thermostat to an old system (currently running a mercury thermostat on it).

There is an extra wire (orange) which you can see both inside the thermostat and also in the image of the furnace. I should be able to use that for the C wire.

You'll notice that the wiring of the furnace is done with wire nuts. All of the instructions to add the C Wire that I can find are assuming that I have a C port on the furnace, which I don't, since this is all done with nuts.

My question is this: on the furnace side, into which wire nut should the orange be joined to get the correct power supplied?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

### You already have a C wire, it's just not called by that name

From a close examination of your furnace's wiring diagram, the fat brown wire it supplies in the thermostat wiring compartment is the C-wire feed from the transformer.  The way your system is wired connects the brown wire in the outdoor-unit cable and the brown wire in the thermostat cable to that brown C-wire feed, so the brown wire that connects to the X terminal on your thermostat *is your C wire!*  As a result of this, just hook that brown wire up to the C terminal on your new thermostat and call it a day.  (If you're wondering what terminal the blue wire goes to on the new thermostat, it went to the B terminal on the old thermostat, so it goes to the O/B terminal on the new thermostat, by the way.)

Comment: Thank you so much for this thoughtful response. Trying it shortly. I greatly appreciate the help.